# Making DataTime.TryParse to return false if only time is passed

Tags: c#

```
    DateTime d;
    return DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out d);
```

Currently if I pass `"3:35:45"` it will parse it **successfully** and the return value is that time plus today's date for its date part.

**But** I want it to actually **fail** and say where is the date?!
**Note** that I don't know or have a specific date time forma like `yyyy-mm-dd` to pass to a `TrayParseExact`

**Note2:** Solution doesn't "have" to use `TryParse`, whatever other solution you can suggest is fine too as long as when I pass only the `time` portion to it, it won't say it is an OK `datetime`

Comment: Can you use `TimeOnly.TryParse()`? I.e., if it returns `true`, you have only parsable time

Comment: @TimSchmelter : Yes, Valid.... and if they jsut pass a time and no date : False

Comment: If you don't know or have a specific date time format, how do you expect users to know what to provide you with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use `TimeOnly` you could use

```
string v = "3:35:45";
bool valid = !TimeOnly.TryParse(v, out _) && DateTime.TryParse(v, out _);
```

Comment: Didn't even know about TimeOnly and DateOnly.... will try now thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault` to force it to return `01/01/0001` for such values. Then simply check that the result is greater than one day after that.

```cs
return 
  DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), null, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault, out var d)
    && d >= DateTime.MinValue.AddDays(1);
```